# Regex to extract 'and' and 'or' and words in between

Tags: java, regex

A sample text:

`field1=value1`    and `field2=[field2Value]` or `field3=field3Value`

I would like to get those separately:

- `field1=value1`
- `and`
- `field2=[field2Value]`
- `or`
- `field3=field3Value`

Note that the text can't start/end with 'or' or 'and' for example these texts should fail

**Ex1:** `and field1=field1Value`

**Ex:2** `field1=field1Value and`

Here what I got so far https://regex101.com/r/TEQujk/1

Comment: I don't think you can have one regex to get individual tokens, and to check the validity of whole string (it will probably work but not advisable)

Comment: @AdrianShum Agreed.  Validation should be done as a separate step, and this might require a formal parser.  The extraction can be done using one of the helpful answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is something you want

```
(?<=^|\band\b|\bor\b) *\b(.*?)\b *(?=$|\band\b|\bor\b)|\b(and|or)\b
```

Basically this pattern matches two different case:

- a string around `and`/`or` (and also begin/end of string)
- `and` `or` themselves

Given a sample of `abc and def or ghi`

- 1st match, group 1: `abc`
- 2nd match, group 2: `and`
- 3rd match, group 1: `def`
- 4th match, group 2: `or`
- 5th match, group 1: `ghi`

Explanation

First part

```
(?<=^|\band\b|\bor\b) *\b(.*?)\b *(?=$|\band\b|\bor\b)
(?<=                )                                   lookbehind
    ^                                                   start of line
     |\band\b                                           or "and" as a whole word
             |\bor\b                                    or "or" as a whole word
                    ) *                                 follow by some spaces
                       \b(.*?)\b                        bunch of words (match as few as possible)
                                  *                      follow by some space
                                    (?=                ) lookahead group
                                       $|\band\b|\bor\b  end of line OR and OR or
```

OR Second Part:

```
|\b(and|or)\b       OR and/or as a whole word
```

---

The above regex only serve the purpose of extracting individual token from the string.  So it does not match your WHOLE string (for you to check validity)

You should either have your logic to check if tokens meaningful, or you can simply have a separate regex to check, which looks like:

```
^(\w+(\s+and\s+|\s+or\s+))*(\w+)$
```

Comment: The pattern has an extra (.  And it doesn't fail if the text ends with 'and'

Comment: "field1=value1 and"
This should fail. 
matcher.matches() should return false.

Comment: You should have a separate regex to check for validity of whole string.  This regex is just for you to extract individual part, so it won't match the whole string.  A simple regex should serve the purpose of validation

Comment: Extracting the text "field1=value1" should return field1=value1 but it doesn't

Comment: @sami Not sure how you tested it but it works when I am testing in  regex101

Comment: I tested with Java and regex101 and both doesn't work, you might made a change the break it. Fix this and this would be the right answer to my question.

Comment: I guess you mean the second one.  I was only aiming to give you an idea on what the regex will look like.  It only match `\w` for the expression part which I expect you to tweak a bit.  e.g. if you always want format of `key=value`, you could change it to `^(\w*=\w*(\s+and\s+|\s+or\s+))*(\w*=\w*)$`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a single call to `String#split()`, using lookarounds which do not consume, whenever seeing an and/or.  Note that I call `String#trim()` on the matches, because the whitespace is not consumed.

```
String input = "field1=value1 and field2=[field2Value] or field3=field3Value";
String[] parts = input.split("(?=\\s+(and|or))|(?<=(and|or)\\s+)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part.trim());
}

field1=value1
and 
field2=[field2Value]
or 
field3=field3Value
```

### Demo

Comment: The regex with split is working perfectly, however this text should not be valid "field1=value1 and" . 
Basically text can't end with 'and' or 'or'

Comment: @sami Validation and extraction are two different things and should be done separately.  I will leave the validation for another question.

Comment: I appreciate your help and answer, however the validation is part of the question see description.

Comment: You should do validation as a separate step.  You do realize that you'll probably need a parser to properly validate all possibilities?

Comment: I will use java code to validate and extract using Pattern, please see http://rextester.com/GQOUVG57836

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="field1=value1 and field2=[field2Value] or field3=field3Value";
    String test[]=str.split("(?=and|or*+)|(\\s)");
    for (String str1:test)
    {
      if(!str1.equals(""))
      System.out.println(str1);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
field1=value1
and
field2=[field2Value]
or
field3=field3Value
```

Comment: I also need to validate the text, for ex text "field1=value1 and" should fail because it ends with 'and'

Answer (score 0):

if there are no spaces between the values and the equals, and there is always a space between the desired arguments, you can simply use

```
inputString.split("\\s+");
```